# WPF / C#: Connect shapes dynamically with lines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I have following XAML-Code:

```
    <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" Height="{Binding Radius}" Fill="{Binding BackColor}" />
                    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" x:Name="_Line"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                <Setter Property="Line.X1" Value="{Binding LineX1}"/>
                <Setter Property="Line.X2" Value="{Binding LineX2}"/>
                <Setter Property="Line.Y1" Value="{Binding LineY1}"/>
                <Setter Property="Line.Y2" Value="{Binding LineY2}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

It's an ItemsControl whose ItemPanel is a Canvas to dynamically place the ellipses from a Obervable Collection I binded to. The placement of the ellipses with the  and the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left values works fine. But it doesn't draw the lines to connect the ellipses.

The Positions for the lines are calculated correctly in the code behind, I checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Line properties should not be applied to the Item Container. Instead, they should be directly set on the Line control in the DataTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" Height="{Binding Radius}"
                     Fill="{Binding BackColor}" />
            <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" x:Name="_Line"
                  X1="{Binding LineX1}" Y1="{Binding LineY1}"
                  X2="{Binding LineX2}" Y1="{Binding LineY2}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that the LineX and LineY property values are relative to the item position.

---

EDIT: An alternative solution with absolute placement of all elements would be not to set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties on the item container (i.e. have no ItemContainerStyle at all).

You would use an Path with an EllipseGeometry instead of an Ellipse and bind the Center property of the EllipseGeometry to a view model property of type `Point` as a replacement for X and Y:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="{Binding Fill}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding Center}"
                                         RadiusX="{Binding Radius}"
                                         RadiusY="{Binding Radius}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Line Stroke="Black"
                      X1="{Binding LineX1}" Y1="{Binding LineY1}"
                      X2="{Binding LineX2}" Y2="{Binding LineY2}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but now the lines are drawed on the wrong positions and the ellipses also are on the wrong position. I would attach a picture but I can't :) Edit: The ellipses have more distance between each other than before and the lines have the right angles but are on the wrong positons. The LineX1-X2-Y1-Y2 Coordinats are right.

Comment: As said the LineX and LineY properties are now relative to the item, i.e. Line.X1 and Line.Y1 are always zero, while Line.X2 and Line.Y2 get the relative coordinates of the line endpoint, i.e. the differences (LineX2 - LineX1) and (LineY2 - LineY1), respectively. Also to draw a centered ellipse you would have to replace the Ellipse control with a Path control that contains an EllipseGeometry.

Comment: An alternative would be to put the Line controls in the ItemTemplate of a second ItemsControl, that does not set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in its ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: Thanks man :D Just one more little question if you don't mind :) I didn't figure out how to hide all lines behind the ellipses, so the ellipses always are on top.

Comment: Set `Panel.ZIndex="1"` on the Path. Please see the edited answer.